# Executing unit test method from a separate windows form

Tags: c#

I called unit test methods on a windows form. On a list box, all unit test methods get displayed.

I wanted to execute all unit test methods displayed on this form in one go.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Why are you not just using a regular unit test runner?

Comment: I was using test explorer even i used vstest.console.exe, but recently my client change the idea and wanted a small form and a button on its top, so that he wanted to see all tests run in one go and result should display on rich text box, same as displayed on VS Test Explorer.

Comment: Why does your client care how you run your unit tests? This is a pretty bizarre requirement, IMO - I'd generally say it's more important to be able to see the results of unit tests from a CI build... What kind of unit tests are you running? There may be a standalone GUI already. (I'm amazed the client wants to waste their money paying for you to write code that doesn't give them any value...)

Comment: I provided same options to them, that creating a separate GUI is not of much value, but as they dont want Jenkins integration on this, there was only option left for me create a batch to run on vstest.console, and client side folks does not want that either and wanted to see a small GUI to trigger run. I understand it's waste of money for client but that is what the requirement is and i will make it this way to make my client happy.

Comment: Well again, what test framework are you using? (The test integration in Visual Studio can run various different kinds.) Given various aspects of a good test runner such as AppDomain isolation and handling parameterized tests, I would start to estimate writing such a tool properly at 4 weeks work to start with. Your client may change their mind when they hear the estimate :)

Comment: I am using MSTest/VS13. I am just a beginner Jake, let me explore more on AppDomain isolation.

Comment: Note that you can run just the console version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx I would *strongly* advise your client not to waste time and money on this. Writing your own test runner is *not* a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and i think i got the solution.
I wanted to call all unit tests from another project to a UI (separate Project)

Code:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public static void TestMethod1()
    {
        SerializingLearn.Articles s = new SerializingLearn.Articles();
        s.sTitle = "a";
        s.sText = "b";
        s.sAuthor = "c";
        s.serialize(@"c:\124.txt");
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public static void TestMethod2()
    {
        SerializingLearn.Articles s = new SerializingLearn.Articles();
        s.sTitle = "a1";
        s.sText = "b1";
        s.sAuthor = "c1";
        s.serialize(@"c:\154.txt");
    }
}
```

If test methods were made static it can be easily called from another project/UI
I can execute these unit tests from that UI, on click of a button.

Comment: These methods aren't test methods. There's no assertions. You also don't have to make methods static in order to call them from code in another assembly, you could've just instantiated the class and called the methods on that instance.

Comment: Sure, I can instantiate the class. UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1 k1 = new UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1();
            k1.TestMethod1();
            k1.TestMethod2();

Comment: That's not the point. How will you determine that this code does what you expect it to? What _are_ these methods testing? Besides that, by manually calling your unit tests, you'll have to update your UI every time you add a test.

Comment: I am mostly adding unit tests for webservices methods which accepts only date or direct call. So user knows these test cases verifies those methods only. I am planning to put a input field (date) here, which accepts date and run methods from here.

Comment: Calling a web service is something that does not belong in a unit test. Are you sure your client doesn't just want a UI with which they can call the web service?